# cntlm password : special characters

Tags: windows-7, proxy, ntlm, cntlm

I just got **cntlm** for my Windows 7 (86) It runs on cmd line and also as service, but i am not able to initiate on command line with my proxy password as it contains special characters. Any way to get rid of this shortcoming. this is what i tried

```
cntlm -g -v -u user@domain -p pwd#$! -l 8085 proxy.company.com:port
```

Comment: i just found out nothing can be done i changed my password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cntlm cannot process the request with password having some special characters like @,$,#, so the only option is to change the password